# setTimeOut function not invoked when the device goes idle - android titanium mobile?

Tags: android, mobile, timeout, titanium

I'm invoking a method using setTimeOut after 20 mins delay. In iPhone its working properly but in android after 20 mins the method not invoked. If we changed to 1 minute, the method gets invoked. I guess there may some issue with device goes idle in android.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use appcelerator background service but there is a limitation of 10 mins for that.